# selenium firefox path setting problems

Tags: selenium

no matter what I do selenium doesn't accept my firefox path in the console where I launch it from. Keep getting the same error.
I also set the path as an environment variable in win 7 64.

I'm pretty much a virgin when it comes to selenium.  Trying to run my first JUNIT test.

Here is the message from selenium.

21:46:43.481 INFO - Command request: getNewBrowserSession[*chrome, http://compendiumdev.co.uk/, ] on session null
21:46:43.497 INFO - creating new remote session
21:46:43.544 INFO - Got result: Failed to start new browser session: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Firefox could not be found in the path!
Please add the directory containing ''firefox.exe'' to your PATH environment
variable, or explicitly specify a path to Firefox like this:
*firefox c:\blah\firefox.exe on session null

Below is my java code

```
package com.eviltester.seleniumtutorials;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class MyFirstSeleniumTests {
    Selenium selenium=null;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome",      
        http://compendiumdev.co.uk/");

        selenium.start();
    }

    @Test
    public void testExported() throws Exception {
        selenium.open("/selenium/search.php");
        selenium.type("q", "Selenium-RC");
        selenium.click("name=btnG");

    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        selenium.stop();
    }
}
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: can u check this http://samueladesoga.wordpress.com/2011/04/26/could-not-start-selenium-session-failed-to-start-new-browser-sesion/ and verify if it solves the problem

Comment: Thanks Anuragh, I assigned the variable to this C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe . Where are we supposed to set the path and add a slash at the end?  Thanks!
I did set it as an environment variable didn't make a change.
Also tried from my console as well.

C:\selenium\selenium_2_44>*firefox C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\
'*firefox' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: U need add that path to existing environment variable "PATH" manually.